# Jquery Autocomplete Combo box - How to load data from database?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to implement autocomplete combobox. I have referenced 'https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#combobox' but i'm getting confusion to where to assign an array to source in the code.

But i'm already implemented autocomplete and here is my code.

```
var autocompleteList = [];
session.run('MATCH (n) RETURN n.nme').then(function (result) {
result.records.forEach(function(record){
autocompleteList.push(record._fields[0]);
});
```

Jquery code

```
$( "#search" ).autocomplete({
  max:10,
  minLength:1,
  source: autocompleteList
});

});
```

Can you please give me some idea to add combo box logic with this code.

Comment: try this [link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jqueryui/jqueryui_autocomplete.htm)

Comment: Thanks! but autocomplete is working for me. I need to expand as autocomplete combo box. There is no example for a combo box in the link which you provided above.

Comment: Combobox uses a nested Autocomplete. In this way you'd want to set the source for your nested Autocomplete as the database. Please review: https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote and apply this to the nested autocomplete in your combobox. Otherwise, post a complete example of you code for review.

Comment: [select2](https://select2.org/) is far better....just saying. It provides you easy of even paginating the results and loading more.. and more as you scroll